# How can I update an object inside array of state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, I have a state of tables.

```
const initialState = {
 allTables: [],
 fetching: true,
 tableId: {},
};
```

allTables is a state that has many objects of table.

```
allTables: Array[16]
```

and each object has id, current_order, type of table.

```
{
id: 1
type: "main"
current_order: null
}
```

So, now what I have is when a user clicks a table, it creates order. What I want to add is that when a user clicks a table, it sends order_id to the reducer, and update the current_order of table object.

```
  case Constants.TABLE_IS_BUSY:
        return { ...state, tableId: action.id }

  case Constants.TABLES_NEW_ORDER_CREATED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            tables: state.allTables.map((id) => {
                if (state.allTables.id === state.tableId) {
                    return Object.assign({}, {
                        state.allTables.current_order: action.order
                    })
                }
                return state
            })

        })
```

So in order to do that, I made reducer like above. When you click table, it triggers TABLE_IS_BUSY and TABLES_NEW_ORDER_CREATED. For TABLE_IS_BUSY, i get table_id of table that a user clicked and change value of tableId of state. But for TABLES_NEW_ORDER_CREATED, it doesn't change the value of current_user... How can I do this correctly?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you have something like:

```
case Constants.TABLES_NEW_ORDER_CREATED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            tables: state.allTables.map((table) => {
                if (table.id === state.tableId) {
                    return Object.assign({}, table, {
                        current_order: action.order
                    })
                }
                else {
                   return Object.assign({}, table)
                }
            })
        })
```